# How to install PCAP for ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, pcap

This must be a relatively newb question but I am still stuck. I know there is a simple solution to this. I've done some googling but could not find an exact answer. Here is the error I get...

```
C:\Ruby193\include\ruby-1.9.1\i386-mingw32>gem install pcap
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pcap:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for gethostbyname() in -lxnet... no
checking for hstrerror()... no
checking for pcap.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

Clearly I am missing some libraries but I not know how to get these nor do I know where they should be located when attempting to install pcap.

mkmf.log

```
    have_library: checking for socket() in -lsocket... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main() {return 0;}
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lsocket  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
c:/users/user/downloads/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsocket
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))socket; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lsocket  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: error: too few arguments to function 'socket'
c:\users\user\downloads\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/winsock2.h:553:35: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { socket(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_library: checking for gethostbyname() in -lxnet... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lxnet  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
c:/users/user/downloads/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lxnet
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))gethostbyname; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lxnet  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:1: error: too few arguments to function 'gethostbyname'
c:\users\user\downloads\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../include/winsock2.h:555:57: note: declared here
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { gethostbyname(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_func: checking for hstrerror()... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
conftest.c: In function 't':
conftest.c:8:53: error: 'hstrerror' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:8:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))hstrerror; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include conftest.c  -L. -LC:/Ruby193/lib -L/usr/local/lib     -lmsvcrt-ruby191  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -limagehlp  "
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\ccbjKHSc.o:conftest.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `hstrerror'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: 
6: /*top*/
7: int main() {return 0;}
8: int t() { hstrerror(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------

have_header: checking for pcap.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -E -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -IC:/Ruby193/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I.    -I/usr/local/include  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <pcap.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: It is semi long. How can I attach it? It does mention things like....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end solution was to not use pcap rub which seems to be fairly outdated.

I tried PCAP rub and continued to run into issues. You can follow the [thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3469827#1041833) here where Jonm ultimately helped me to get up and running.