# Ruby/Windows Pcap (pcaplet)

Tags: ruby, windows, pcap, libpcap, winpcap

Is there currently anyway to get 'pcap/pcaplet' working under windows/ruby?

I've seen (costly/paid) packet sniffing software for windows that lets you sniff clear-text irc traffic.
I thought it would be nice for there to be free software that could do this. (yes we have wireshark but it's on a per-packet analysis).

I wanted to capture the traffic with pcap and then parse out the data I need to make a nice/simple irc capture program in ruby.

However it seems you can't get pcap/ruby to play nice in windows and Google has shown a lot of people failing to get it working.

Does anyone know of a way to run this under windows in ruby?

Comment: They claim success [in the thread linked from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885237/how-to-install-pcap-for-ruby-on-windows?rq=1), give it a shot?

Comment: I'm curious as you are, but do you have the devkit installed on your Ruby installation? I'm not sure if that would help either.